# How to handle width of image inside the ListView in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

My image is inside the `ListView`. And I want to give custom width to my image. But `width` property doesn't work for me. I am able to give custom `height` but the width property is not working.

**Here is what image looks like:**

[image: Sample image]

**Here is the sample code:**

```dart
Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('Sample App'),
  ),
  body: ListView(
    children: <Widget>[
      Image.network(
        'https://assets.website-files.com/5e3c45dea042cf97f3689681/5e417cd336a72b06a86c73e7_Flutter-Tutorial-Header%402x.jpg',
      width: 100,
      height: 200,
      fit: BoxFit.fill,
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By wrapping your *Image* widget inside *Center* widget, you can control the width and height of the image.

```
    Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Sample App'),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          Center(                // --> new change
            child: Image.network(
              'https://assets.website-files.com/5e3c45dea042cf97f3689681/5e417cd336a72b06a86c73e7_Flutter-Tutorial-Header%402x.jpg',
              width: 100,
              height: 200,
              fit: BoxFit.fill,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

**EDIT:**
If you would like to align your image other than the center, you can wrap it inside the Align widget.

```
    Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Sample App'),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            child: Image.network(
              'https://assets.website-files.com/5e3c45dea042cf97f3689681/5e417cd336a72b06a86c73e7_Flutter-Tutorial-Header%402x.jpg',
              width: 100,
              height: 100,
              fit: BoxFit.fill,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Comment: If you have any parent widget that has any effect on the image (in my case I have ClipRRect) then instead of wrapping your image with the center widget, wrap your parent widget with the center widget.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I was trying to create many children to fill a SliverGrid widget, but the constructor I was using for the widget (SliverGrid.count) requiered a crossAxisCount attribute to indicate how many items per row. This int attribute was creating the items with the same height and width (90 x 90) and I couldn't change this values no matter what I tried, until I found out the aspect ratio was 1 (which was the reason for the same height and width). To do what I wanted (which was a little bit more height than width) I changed the aspect ratio to:

```
childAspectRatio: 0.5
```